# How U-V-N camera coordinate system explained with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, matrix

I am confused of u-v-n camera coordinate system when deducing the model-view matrix specified by the function:

```
void gluLookAt(GLdouble eyeX,  GLdouble eyeY,  GLdouble eyeZ,  GLdouble centerX,  GLdouble centerY,  GLdouble centerZ,  GLdouble upX,  GLdouble upY,  GLdouble upZ);
```

if we call this function ,then we get a u-v-n coordinate system ,in which **n = center-eye**.
it looks like this:

[image: UVN Camera]

And this u-v-n is left handle coordinate system .

**parts confused me :**

Can this u-v-n coordinate be the so called camera coordinate many books said ?

And I often read from some tutorial or textbook,said camera coordinate system is right-hand,so why we construct a left-hand u-v-n coordinate to deduce the model-view matrix specified by gluLookAt ,just for convenience ?

**update**

After reading your answer and investigation,I understood it this way:

1)u-v-n coordinate system is left-hand,and camera coordinate is right-hand,this is the fact.

2) when calculate the matrix,OpenGL will flip the n axis to -n instead,thus make it still a right-hand system,see [gluLookAt API](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml)  and [GluLookAt code implementation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluLookAt_code) for details.

Comment: `uvn` is left handed indeed, but `vun` is right handed. So change the name and make `v` the up vector, `n` the direction vector and `u` the horizontal vector.

Comment: View-space is generally right-handed and the projection matrix will flip it (it inverts the Z-axis) since clip-space is left-handed. This convention (for view-space) is actually not necessary, but it is typical for fixed-function OpenGL. It is absolutely required that clip-space be left-handed, however.

Answer (score 3):

To transform from camera coordinates to `uvn` define points *T* for target, *C* for camera and vector **up** for the up direction. The follow the steps below:

[image: CS]

where the `norm()` function normalizes a vector to `magnitude()=1`

Comment: Thanks for replying!And late to reply you due to SO blocked in China.Your formula is right.But what really puzzed me is how glLookAt calculate the matrix.It flip the n aixs and make it still a right-hand coordinate system.see update.

Comment: It must flp two axis then. Flip the **n** and the **u** axis.